# How to specific columns by taking the name from a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to rename the column names with the row values, but I need to use a subset of column names from row values and update those only for the rest of the columns keep the column name as it is. How can this be done in pandas?

What I have tried was using `df.iloc` the specific row and columns which I want to be as my column names

```
df.columns = df.iloc[2, 11:62]
```

I only need to change the index 11 until 62.

But the script did not work, it said that the length is mismatch.

Below is the sample input and expected output,

input is similar like this

```
1  2   3   4   5  6  7  8   9
a  b   c   d   e  f  g  h   i
```

and I expect the column names changes only for 4 to 8 columns

```
1  2   3   d   e  f  g  h   9
a  b   c   d   e  f  g  h   i
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: can u  supply the input and the desired output , its hard to deduce from the question you have posted

Comment: I put it at the answer box

Comment: @yangyang Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with `df.iloc`:

```
In [3091]: df
Out[3091]: 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  I
```

Create a `dictionary` with column names and values for index `[3:8]` using [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp):

```
In [3092]: cols_dict = dict(zip(df.iloc[:, 3:8].columns, df.iloc[:, 3:8].values[0]))
```

Pass this `dict` to `rename` method:

```
In [3095]: df.rename(columns=cols_dict, inplace=True)

In [3096]: df
Out[3096]: 
   1  2  3  d  e  f  g  h  9
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sample dataframe and change the columns as you have asked, let me know if this is what you are looking for...

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

row_values = list(df.iloc[0].values)
df_columns = list(df.columns)
new_columns = row_values[:2]+df_columns[2:]
df.columns = new_columns
```

Just change the `new_columns = row_values[:2]+df_columns[2:]` line according to your needs.